# How to find "Crossover" operator for Genetic algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

Disclosure : Yes, this is my homework.

I having the following problem: I have 50 men, 50 women, and 50 dogs. Each one of them has a list of his favorites of each of the others. For example, woman number 6 has a list of her 50 favorite men sorted from the least favorite to the most favorite, and a list her 50 favorite dogs sorted from the least favorite to the most favorite. The men have lists for women and dogs, and the dogs have lists for women and men.

I need to find the best match that I can so the women, men, and dogs will be as happy as possible. I need to do it by genetic algorithms.

Let's say I have matches A and B (where I match all 150 entities to 50 families so every woman/man/dog appears only once).

How do I crossover A and B ? 
Every crossover I could think about leads me to the following problem: someone will appear twice, while others won't appear at all.

For example if I randomly choose `X` between 1 and 50, and take the first X families from A and the 50-x second families from B, there is a chance of about 0 that the new match is legit and everyone appears only once.

How do I approach such a problem ?

Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean "do it by genetic algorithms"?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it, none perfect.

**A** and **B** could take turns suggesting families to **C**. Since **C** starts with a pool of 50 free men, 50 free women and 50 free dogs, it can form the first suggested family. If a suggested family requires a member, say a dog, that is already in a family, the new family can choose a dog at random from the pool of free dogs.

**A** could contribute a set of, say, 10 families to **C**, then **B** could contribute whichever of its families are still viable in **C** (that is, the ones compatible with the 10 from **A**). Leftover men, women and dogs woud form families at random.

**C** could inherit the man-woman pairings of **A** and the woman-dog pairings of **B**, without any conflict.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,But i'm not sure if it legal in the crossover stage to choose randomly things that i couldn't inherit from my parents, It is OK to choose randomly from which of the parents to inherit some "gene" (gene is a family for example) ,but when i don't have a suitable gene to inherit i don't think it is allowed to just randomly generate other genes. Randomness comes after the crossover in the mutation stage. I don't say that your suggestion won't work, it probably will, but i'm not sure it's legal Genetic algorithm.

Comment: What do you mean "legal"? And are you sure you want to define `gene` as a family?

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution to the problem, maybe it will help some one in the future.
I must admit that it feels a little bit like a "hack" but it is totally legit.

I have two matches A (contains 50 families) and B (contains 50 families), each family represented by a tuple size of 3 `{ WomanId,ManId,DogId }`

The crossover goes like this :

- sort A and B by `womanId`,now in family number `i` in A and in family number `i` in B the `WomanId` =`i`
- Copy A to the child vector C
- Replace the dogs in C to the dogs in B

What is happening is that C inherits the Woman,Man couples from A , and the Woman,Dog couples from B.

Just for completeness, you don't always sort by WomanId, you choose randomly woman,man,dog and then you copy the others from A or from B randomly.

It actually works (i also added mutations), i randomly generated 1000 matches and and the run the algorithm, the number is the cost of the best match i could find in the current generation

[image]

The cost is just the summation of every woman/man/dog rankings of his family members (the lower the rank the better)

Answer (score 0):

Since you already found a solution, I want to give you another idea for exploration and comparison should you want to deepen your insights of this assignment.

You could represent it with 3 permutations of size 50 each representing the assignment of woman, man, and dog to a certain family. That is the first entry in each permutation represents which woman, man, and dog form family one and so on. In each permutation every number occurs only once and thus every woman, man, or dog is only assigned to one family. You can then use e.g. partially matched crossover (PMX) that you apply to all permutations either with the same breakpoints or independently. In mutation you could choose to swap two or more men/women/dogs and thus assign them to different families.